# Is there a way to estimate Poisson interaction effect in python statsmodels?

Tags: python, statsmodels

Does statsmodels in Python have a way to estimate interaction with a 95% confidence interval? This would be the linear combination of the model's parameter estimates.

Given the example below, I would like to get the effect of being in arm 'b' among people in place 'there', it would require estimating the linear combination of model parameters:

*Beta* arm + *Delta* arm*place, but also including the appropriate confidence interval.

I'm aware of `mod.params` and `mod.conf_int()`, but does statsmodels have another methods for linear combinations?

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import patsy
import numpy as np

cases = np.array([random.randint(0,10) for i in range(200)])
arm = [random.choice(['a', 'b']) for i in range(200)]
place = [random.choice(['here', 'there']) for i in range(200)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'arm': arm, 'place': place})
exog = patsy.dmatrix('arm + place + arm * place', df, return_type='dataframe')

mod = sm.GLM(endog=cases, exog=exog, family=sm.families.Poisson()).fit()
mod.summary()
```

Comment: The easiest is to use `results.get_prediction` method if all exog are specified, either for the mean prediction (exponentiated) or for linear component.  `t_test` computes the statistics for linear combination of parameters, but needs checking that the confidence interval is for the correct statistic.

Comment: Ah, I see. So it would be like: ```means = np.array([[0,1,0,1],
                  [0,1,0,0]])

est_means = mod.get_prediction(means)
est_means.conf_int()
est_means.predicted_mean```

Answer (score 0):

[Bollen's Delta Method](https://statisticalhorizons.com/wp-content/uploads/Delta-Method-RM-20042.pdf) is frequently used to get the confidence interval for the linear combination `b1 * x + b2 * x * z`.

I'm not sure how and to what extent [Statsmodels incorporates the Delta Method](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/2296).

If you want to go down the `results.get_prediction` route just make sure all the 'other covariates' (if any) are set to their sample or population mean.